# List of lists vs dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, math, dictionary

In Python, are there any advantages / disadvantages of working with a list of lists versus working with a dictionary, more specifically when doing numerical operations with them? I'm writing a class of functions to solve simple matrix operations for my linear algebra class. I was using dictionaries, but then I saw that `numpy` uses list of lists instead, so I guess there must be some advantages in it.

Example: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` as opposed to `{0:[1,2,3],1:[4,5,6],2:[7,8,9]}`

Comment: It Depends. Read a data structure textbook on how hash tables work. There's a whole bunch of differences that make one faster for some use cases but slower for others.

Comment: `lists` will maintain an order while `dicts` are unordered, IMHO for matrix related operations lists are more appropriate.

Comment: numpy doesn't use lists of lists: it might *display* a 2d array in the form of a list of lists, but it's using a dedicated array type that's more efficient and versatile than a list of lists.

Comment: It does depend however, if you have a very sparsely populated matrix, then rather than `list`s full of `None`s, a `dict` might make more sense.

Comment: @Lattyware Intuitively, it seems like even a mildly sparse list with many deletions / inserts in the middle (which would require a lot of copying in a `list`) might be better with a `dict`. (Or it might not because complexity theory doesn't directly correlate to performance in practice, of course.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this largely depends on how you plan on using this structure.

Python's dictionaries are (like most) unordered by default. If you plan on iterating over your data like such, you shouldn't use a dictionary:

```
for list in dict.keys():
    for elem in list:
        # Logic
```

Likewise, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use a dictionary with the keys 1, 2, 3 ... when they have little value other than an index. Dictionaries also take up more space in memory due to the hashing process.

If you plan on accessing items by element (which it sounds like you want to), you'll still want to use a List. Index lookup in a list of O(1), same as in a Dictionary. The only difference is when you're looking up some key value, instead of an index (which will be faster than in a dictionary).

You should really only consider using a dictionary when you have some sort of **key-value relationship** mapping, in which a meaningful key needs to be searched for to retrieve a related value. This doesn't sound like one of those cases. Stick with a list-of-lists.

---

<sub>That's not to say Dictionaries are a bad data structure. Ruby and Python introduced me to them, and they're extremely useful for any of those afore-mentioned mapping problems (which I find I run into quite a lot). They're just useful for a specific class of problems, and this isn't one of them.</sub>

Answer (score 13):

When the keys of the dictionary are `0`, `1`, ..., `n`, a `list` will be faster, since no hashing is involved. As soon as the keys are not such a sequence, you need to use a `dict`.

Comment: I thought `list` was doubly linked list, and look up time in a `list` is O(n), while it is O(1) in `dict`, so look up is slower in a `list`

Comment: @Akavall Python lists are not doubly linked lists.

Comment: @Akavall list is implemented as a dynamic array, [How are lists implemented?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented)